# OBS will not load with Razer Ripsaw plugged in

Tags: video, webcam

Checking if the capture device is detected

```
 hutber@hutber:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Razer Ripsaw X: Razer Ripsaw X (usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

I also have a camlink that works:

```
hutber@hutber:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Cam Link 4K: Cam Link 4K (usb-0000:00:14.0-6.1):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

OBS output

```
info: v4l2-input: Start capture from 
error: v4l2-input: Unable to open device
error: v4l2-input: Initialization failed, errno: No such file or directory
info: xshm-input: Geometry 2560x1440 @ 2560,0
[png_pipe @ 0x556b01ddb000] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
info: adding 64 milliseconds of audio buffering, total audio buffering is now 64 milliseconds (source: Mic/Aux)

info: xshm-input: Geometry 2560x1440 @ 5120,0
info: xshm-input: Geometry 2560x1440 @ 0,0
info: xshm-input: Geometry 2560x1440 @ 5120,0
info: v4l2-input: Start capture from /dev/video2
error: v4l2-input: Unable to open device
error: v4l2-input: Initialization failed, errno: No such file or directory
info: v4l2-input: Start capture from /dev/video0
info: v4l2-input: Input: 0
info: v4l2-input: Resolution: 3840x2160
info: v4l2-input: Pixelformat: YU12
info: v4l2-input: Linesize: 3840 Bytes
info: v4l2-input: Framerate: 30.00 fps
info: v4l2-input: /dev/video0: select timeout set to 166666 (5x frame periods)
info: v4l2-input: Start capture from /dev/video2
error: v4l2-input: Unable to open device
error: v4l2-input: Initialization failed, errno: No such file or directory
info: alsa-input: PCM 'default' rate set to 44100
info: alsa-input: PCM 'default' channels set to 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Of course without the ripsaw being plugged in, OBS opens and works perfectly. But I am not completely stuck in my understanding as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Good question sorry `20.04`

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will help anybody else but, after playing around allot with the settings.ini I realised this won't help me at all however I did get the video working by deleting the `.config/obs-studio` folder which made me realise it must be the settings saved for the cameras.

As I did not want to lose all my OBS structure I deleted every camera in each scene, reset OBS and added a camera again.. and it worked.

Comment: This is a modification of your Question, Not an Answer. [Edit] your Question to add information.

Comment: @waltinator thank you for commenting. However this is an answer, and the solution. If I edited the question to include this, there would be no answer. Just the solution?